# Correspondence between material fonts and HTML elements

Tags: html, css, fonts, polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to figure out how to use `paper-styles`. The documentation [says](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles):

> The  component provides simple ways to use Material Design CSS styles in your application. The following imports are available:
>
> ...
>
> - [typography.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/typography.html): Material Design [font](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-styles) styles and sizes

`typography.html` defines several mixins, for example:

- `--paper-font-display4: {`
- `--paper-font-display3: {`
- `--paper-font-display2: {`
- `--paper-font-display1: {`
- `--paper-font-headline: {`
- `--paper-font-title: {`
- `--paper-font-subhead: {`
- `--paper-font-body2: {`
- `--paper-font-body1: {`

My question is: which HTML element should I use with these? For example, is `font-display4` seems to be the equivalent of `h1`, but I am a big confused: is there a some kind of correspondence? Or, shall I just always use `<p>`?

NOTE: Cross asked [as an issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/issues/104) in paper-style's Github page

Comment: this sounds like a question to ask the people who make paper-styles, so that you can explain this is information that's missing, and then they can update their documentation accordingly and help not just you, but everyone. Asking on Stackoverflow in this case is a good way to get an answer but then not help anyone else out.

Comment: I thought maybe I missed it... that's why I wrote here!

Comment: even if you missed it, the people with absolutely the most qualifications to answer your "did I miss it?" question are the people who make paper-styles =) At the very least, ask them *in addition* to asking here, and then you can even add the link to your question in your post.

Comment: Done. Added a link to the issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Material Design Lite instead of Polymer if you are just trying to build a regular website.
[getmdl.io](http://getmdl.io)

Comment: I am not building a regular website... not sure why you had that impression!